# Unable to parse JSON response in android studio

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to build a simple weather app. I am using forecast.io and just trying to extract the summary, temperature and precipitation. So far I have been able to get the response from the site but I am not able to parse it and log just the three values I mentioned above. Here is my logCat response:

```
12-12 13:55:45.528    1286-2153/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc 25643:sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather/u0a57 for activity sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather/.MainActivity
12-12 13:55:45.536  25643-25643/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-12 13:55:45.539   1858-25629/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr﹕ Hotword detection finished
12-12 13:55:45.539    1858-2248/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr﹕ Stopping hotword detection.
12-12 13:55:45.685  25643-25643/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather-2/lib/x86
12-12 13:55:45.888     942-1780/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
12-12 13:55:45.891  25643-25664/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-12 13:55:45.894  25643-25643/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb401c8a0, tid 25643
12-12 13:55:45.952  25643-25664/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab7bf010, tid 25664
12-12 13:55:45.965  25643-25664/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-12 13:55:46.003  25643-25664/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-12 13:55:46.003  25643-25664/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabdffbe0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-12 13:55:46.123   1858-25660/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/Search.SearchUrlHelper﹕ Auth token not ready, no auth header set.
12-12 13:55:46.273    1286-1305/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather/.MainActivity: +771ms
12-12 13:55:46.281    1286-1298/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@149f411 (uid=10014 pid=2154)
12-12 13:55:46.302    2154-2219/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4013030
12-12 13:55:47.802  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value {"latitude":37.329586,"longitude":-122.027337,"timezone":"America\/Los_Angeles","offset":-8,"currently":{"time":1449908733,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","nearestStormDistance":32,"nearestStormBearing":39,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":47.6,"apparentTemperature":43.87,"dewPoint":42.72,"humidity":0.83,"windSpeed":7.94,"windBearing":329,"visibility":8.66,"cloudCover":0.19,"pressure":1017.02,"ozone":334.34},"minutely":{"summary":"Clear for the hour.","icon":"clear-night","data":[{"time":1449908700,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449908760,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449908820,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449908880,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449908940,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909000,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909060,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909120,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909180,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909240,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909300,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909360,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909420,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909480,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909540,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909600,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909660,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909720,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909780,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909840,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909900,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449909960,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910020,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910080,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910140,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910200,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910260,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910320,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910380,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910440,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910500,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910560,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910620,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910680,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910740,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910800,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910860,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910920,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449910980,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911040,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911100,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911160,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911220,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911280,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911340,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911400,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911460,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911520,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911580,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911640,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911700,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911760,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911820,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911880,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449911940,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449912000,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1449912060,"precipIntensity":0,"precipP
12-12 13:55:47.802  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
12-12 13:55:47.802  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
12-12 13:55:47.802  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
12-12 13:55:47.802  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather.MainActivity$getWeather.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:31)
12-12 13:55:47.803  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather.MainActivity$getWeather.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:24)
12-12 13:55:47.803  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
12-12 13:55:47.803  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-12 13:55:47.803  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
12-12 13:55:47.803  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
12-12 13:55:47.803  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
12-12 13:55:47.803  25643-25663/sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is my mainActivity code:

```
package sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String url = ("https://api.forecast.io/forecast/fee692c335fd7e561223c520322731e1/37.329586,-122.027337");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new getWeather().execute();
    }

    class getWeather extends AsyncTask<String, String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            JsonGetter jsonGetter = new JsonGetter();
            String response = jsonGetter.getJSON(url);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String summary = jsonObject.getString("summary");
                    String temperature = jsonObject.getString("temperature");
                    String rainProb = jsonObject.getString("precipProbability");
                    Log.e("Summary: ", summary );
                    Log.e("Temperature: ",temperature);
                    Log.e("Probability of rain: ", rainProb);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I know I haven't extracted the URL string from strings.xml or used URLConnection but this is just a test and I wasnt to know why the JSON is not getting parsed.
Here is my JSONGEtter class:

```
package sidd.tisb.lms.sidsstudios.weather;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Siddharth on 12/12/2015.
 */
public class JsonGetter {

    String response;

    public String getJSON(String URL) {
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } {

        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why I am not getting log statements displaying the summary, temperature and precipitation?
Thanks!!!

Comment: You might had make mistake in parsing especially in "type"

Comment: How would I fix this?